# DB requery with php for envoriment monitoring

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I am new here and this is my first post
I need help for a college project.
We are programming a raspberry pie so that is measures temperature and air humidity and visualize the data on an html page.
But we have a problem to make the visualize right. 
We take the data from myadminphp and show it graphically, but the time stamp is not steady it change the time to time at the moment minus 3 hours but we want to have it fixed every 3 hours.

Php code:

```
$lastDatetime = $db->query("select date_time 
                            from measurements 
                            where id=(
                                        select max(id) 
                                        from measurements
                                    )")
                    ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["date_time"];
$thisDay = $lastDatetime;
$dataLastSevenDays = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 56; $i++) {
    $maxTemperatureThisDay = $db->query("select value 
                                         from measurements 
                                         where date_time like '" . substr($thisDay, 0, 13) . "%' 
                                           and channel = 1 
                                         limit 1"
                                         )
                            ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["value"]; 
    //channel 1 Temp
    $maxBrightnessThisDayThisDay = 
        $db->query("select value 
                    from measurements 
                    where date_time like '" . substr($thisDay, 0, 13) . "%' 
                      and channel = 2 
                    limit 1")
            ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["value"]; //channel 2 Licht

    $maxHumidityThisDay = 
        $db->query("select value 
                    from measurements 
                    where date_time like '" . substr($thisDay, 0, 13) . "%' 
                      and channel = 4 
                    limit 1")
            ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["value"]; //channel 4 Luftfeuchtigkeit
    $thisDay = date_sub(new DateTime($thisDay), new DateInterval('PT10800S'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $dataLastSevenDays[$i] = array($thisDay, $maxTemperatureThisDay, $maxBrightnessThisDayThisDay, $maxHumidityThisDay); 
}
```

the html code:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('temperature').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'line',
                            data: {
                                    labels: [
<?php
    for ($i = 56; $i > 0; $i--) {
        echo '"' . $dataLastSevenDays[$i][0] . '",';
    }
?>
                                    ],
                             datasets: [{
                                        label: "gemessene Temperatur",
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(16, 119, 237)',
                                        data: [
<?php
    for ($i = 56; $i > 0; $i--) {
        echo '"' . $dataLastSevenDays[$i][1] . '",';
    }
?>
                                            ]}]
                                },
                                options: {}
                            });
</script>
```

Comment: what is an envoriment ?

Comment: ?`myadminphp` Do you mean `phpMyAdmin` if so thats a Tool not a database